# How to list out ng-model attribute's values?

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way to list out all the ng-model attribute values? For example..

```
<input type="text" ng-model="person.name"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="person.age" />
```

i would like to get the list[person.name,person.age] of ng-model attribute values

Comment: you can use ng-repeat over person and get the values..

Comment: Kavitha, i would like to get the ng-model attribute values, not ng-model values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to make a directive. Your template could be:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="attribute" />
```

Then in the code, you would iterate over every attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to completely figure out what you want.

Since `ng-model` reflects your *model* and your *controller* has access to your *model*, you can programmatically access your *model* inside your *controller*.

Comment: my need is to collect the model name(not the value) used for ng-model attribute programatically. My requirement is if user saves the model (using local storage) and later if user tries the page, the saved model could be red from local storage and be placed in the scope to show the saved values in screen. But what if the page misses some fields when user tries next time(a week later). So i want to read all the models and try to initialize models that are there in the screen.